# get Json values and Json string from Json Array in SQL Server

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a JSON string like this:

```json
{
    "success": "true",
    "data": [
              { "ID": 1, "name": "abc" },
              { "ID": 2, "name": "def" }
            ]
}
```

I need output like below:

| ID | name | JsonString |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | {"ID": 1, "name": "abc"} |
| 2 | def | {"ID": 2, "name": "def"} |

I need the query in SQL Server

Comment: SQL Server 2008 (which is *completely* unsupported, and has been for **over 2 years**) and 2012 have no [native] support for JSON. Perhaps it's time to get those upgrades done. 2012 only has ~9 months of support left too, so no better time like the present if you need support for JSON in your environments.

Comment: it is in Sql server 2016

Comment: *"it is in Sql server 2016 "* Then *why* did you tag SQL Server 2012 and 2008 initially, and why have you also now tagged 2019..? If you are going to use the version tag, just tag the version you are ***really*** using... New versions of products often bring *new* functionality and *can* also remove it. Spamming version tags (especially the wrong ones) doesn't help those you are asking for (free) help from (in their own time) help you.

Comment: JSON support, however, was added in SQL Server 2016. I suggest having a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and having a search, as there are plenty of answers showing the use of `OPENJSON`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only interesting things here are the initial path to `OPENJSON` (since we only care about `data`) and the property `JsonString` reflecting the original JSON, which needs a path and an override.

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{"success":"true","data":[{"ID":1,"name":"abc"},{"ID":2,"name":"def"}]}';

SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.data')
WITH (ID INT, name VARCHAR(100), JsonString NVARCHAR(MAX) '$' AS JSON)
```